# Exclude subsets from a table which has superset values too

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1 has employee ids and codes where each employee has both super-set code and subset codes.

```sql
+-------------+------+
| Employee ID | Code |
+-------------+------+
|         111 |   18 |
|         111 |   19 |
|         111 |   20 |
|         111 |   21 |
|         222 |   40 |
|         222 |   41 |
|         222 |   42 |
+-------------+------+
```

Table2 has super-set code and subset code.

```sql
+---------------+-------------+
| Superset code | Subset code |
+---------------+-------------+
|            18 |          19 |
|            18 |          20 |
|            18 |          21 |
|            40 |          41 |
|            40 |          42 |
+---------------+-------------+
```

I want output with employee id and super-set code alone.
Expected result table:

```sql
+-------------+------+
| Employee ID | Code |
+-------------+------+
|         111 |   18 |
|         222 |   40 |
+-------------+------+
```

How can I derive this output using sql query?

Comment: Don't post images of word documents; put the text (data) in your question as text. Preferably provide DDL and DML statements, however, if not then tabular formated `text`.#

Comment: @Lakshmi, When you post data of tables, please format it through https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for example.

Comment: Have you even tried anything???  If not, get to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.supersetcode = t1.code);
```

For performance, you want an index on `table2(supersetcode)`.

Comment: Thanks that works! I was working on where not exists and it was taking too much time

Comment: @Lakshmi if Gordon's answer has resolve your problem/question, please accept this.